# How do I prevent equation stretching in inline math mode?

Tags: formatting, inline

This only happens when I have something like `$a = b$` in a paragraph. I have used `${a = b}$`, and that works fine, but is there something I can add to my preamble so I do not need to add the braces every time? Thanks in advance.[image: stretched inline equation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add to your preamble

```latex
\thickmuskip=5mu
\medmuskip=4mu minus 2mu
```

which will kill the stretchability around relation and operation symbols. But so much stretching as you show means you have something weird in your text, because it's not possible that only the spaces around `=` are stretched and not those between words. Unless you set `\spaceskip` with no stretchability, of course.